# Two questions about the use of "eternal" (αἰώνιος, aiōnios) in Jude 1:7

Tags: greek, grammar

Jude 1:7 ends with "*are set forth for an example, suffering the vengeance of eternal fire.*",
which in the original Greek is:

| English | Greek | Romanized | Strong's | Root | Romanized | Grammar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| are set forth for | πρόκεινται | prokeintai | G4295 | πρόκειμαι | prokeima | V-PNI-3P |
| an example, | δεῖγμα | deigma | G1164 | δεῖγμα | deigma | N-ASN |
| fire. | πυρὸς | pyros | G4442 | πῦρ | pyr | N-GSN |
| of eternal | αἰωνίου | aiōniou | G166 | αἰώνιος | aiōnios | A-GSN |
| the vengeance | δίκην | dikēn | G1349 | δίκη | dikē | N-ASF |
| suffering | ὑπέχουσαι | hypechousai | G5254 | ὑπέχω | hypechō | V-PAP-NPF |

The adjective "eternal" is neuter.
It can't refer to "vengeance" or "suffering", as they are feminine.

But both "example" and "fire" are feminine.

- Does Greek grammar require that "eternal" describe "fire", or could it instead describe "example"?
- Either way, could "eternal" be understood as as a reference to God (the fire comes from God)?

Comment: The literal, interlinear translation [EGNT] is _are set forth as an example of fire eternal penalty undergoing_. The 'example' (of 'molten' - lava or meteor or whatever - falling on men) is an example of 'fire eternal penalty undergoing'. Conceptually, yes, the example of 'molten' is fire eternal. But fire eternal _as a penalty_. And yes, conceptually, the only source of anything _eternal_ is the eternal God. But, frankly, I cannot see a real question here, other than to describe the literal words on the page. The rest is what might be termed 'interpretation' or 'concept'.

Comment: @NigelJ, I'm not asking how it *should* be interpreted. I'm asking whether it *could* be a grammatically correct translation.

Comment: No, it cannot be a _translation_ as it is grammatically incorrect and lacking in content. The example is temporal, the reality of the example is eternal. Only God is eternal.

Answer (score 1):

In Jude 1:7, the adjective, αἰωνίου, must modify the noun, πυρὸς, because both are **genitive, neuter singular**.

In answer to the OP's specific question, αἰωνίου cannot modify:

- δίκην (penalty) because it is in the wrong case, viz, accusative
- δεῖγμα (example) because it is in the wrong case, viz, accusative
- ὑπέχουσαι (undergoing/suffering) because it is a verb-participle and not a noun

All the above is shown clearly in the OP's helpful table.

Further, the noun theos (= "god") does not occur in the immediate vicinity of V7 - the closest occurrence is in V1, 4, 21 & 25.  Thus, this text cannot establish that "eternal fire" is from God.  That must be established from other places.

"Fire of God" only occurs in two places, and in the OT, namely, Job 1:16 and 2 Kings 1:12 which discusses such fire destroying that on which it fell, destroying it completely.

However, "fire from heaven" occurs more often and the implication is that such fire does proceed from God (eg, 2 Kings 1:12, 1 Chron 21:26).  See also 2 Kings 1:10, 14. In the NT this phrase, clearly alluding to those in the OT, occurs in Luke 9:54, 17:29, Rev 13:13, 20:9, again, always indicating that such fire consumes completely on which it falls.

Lastly, the phrase "eternal fire" only occurs in two other places, namely Matt 18:8 and 25:41, again with the adjective immediately following the noun as in Jude.  However, in the two instances in Matthew are accusative; while Jude it is genitive.

**APPENDIX - "Burn with Fire"**

The expression, “Burn with fire” is a quintessentially Hebraic expression. While it is true that “burn with fire” is technically redundant, it was an expression used to convey a feeling of intensity and complete destruction, ie, not merely scorched. Here is a sample:

- Ex 12:10 - And you shall not leave any of it over until morning, but whatever is left of it until morning, you shall **burn with fire** [= completely destroy it]
- Ex 29:14 - But the flesh of the bull and its hide and its refuse, you shall **burn with fire** [= completely destroy it] outside the camp; it is a sin offering
- Lev 8:32 - The remainder of the flesh and of the bread you shall **burn in the fire** [= completely destroy it].
- Lev 13:57 - and if it appears again in the garment, whether in the warp or in the woof, or in any article of leather, it is an outbreak; the article with the mark shall be **burned in the fire** [= completely destroyed].
- Lev 16:27 - But the bull of the sin offering and the goat of the sin offering, whose blood was brought in to make atonement in the holy place, shall be taken outside the camp, and they shall **burn their hides, their flesh, and their refuse in the fire**. [= completely destroy it]
- Deut 7:25 - The graven images of their gods you are to **burn with fire** [= completely destroy it]; you shall not covet the silver or the gold that is on them, nor take it for yourselves, or you will be snared by it, for it is an abomination to the LORD your God.
- Josh 11:6 - Then the LORD said to Joshua, "Do not be afraid because of them, for tomorrow at this time I will deliver all of them slain before Israel; you shall hamstring their horses and **burn their chariots with fire** [= completely destroy them].
- Ps 46:9 - Then the LORD said to Joshua, "Do not be afraid because of them, for tomorrow at this time I will deliver all of them slain before Israel; you shall hamstring their horses and **burn their chariots with fire** [completely destroy them].
- Jer 43:13 - He will also shatter the obelisks of Heliopolis, which is in the land of Egypt; and the temples of the gods of Egypt he will **burn with fire** [= completely destroy].
- Eze 23:47 - The company will stone them with stones and cut them down with their swords; they will slay their sons and their daughters and **burn their houses with fire** [= completely destroy them].

See also Matt 3:12, Luke 3:17

There are two important exceptions to this general pattern of Scripture which will be shown not to be exceptions:

- Ex 3:2, 3 where the LORD appeared in the burning bush and Moses was instructed to remove his sandals and no come too close or be destroyed.
- Deut 5:32 discusses the mountain burning with fire (but the mountain was not burned up) showing that at the giving of the 10 commandments, anyone who came close to the mountain would be destroyed by fire

This supports the frequent contention that God, in His capacity as perfectly Holy, is described as a “*consuming fire*” and sinners cannot stand in the presence of such a holy God. Heb 12:29, Deut 4:24, 9:3, Ps 50:3, Isa 29:6, 30:27, 30, 33:14, Ex 24:17, etc.

Comment: _They engaged in avid feasting._ Surely an adjective may modify a participle ?

Comment: @NigelJ - in "fearlessly feasting" in Jude 1:12, the "fearlessly" is an ADVERB, not a adjective.

Comment: Yes, indeed. That is understood. But is there a rule that an adjective _cannot_ modify a participle. In concept, my example indicates that it can.

Comment: @NigelJ - even if that is true, ὑπέχουσαι is too far from αἰωνίου for the two to be directly connected.  In any case, αἰωνίου almost always follows the noun it modifies, as is the case here.